# jQuery AJAX success handler not functioning as expected

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm experiencing a very strange problem with jQuery and IE. I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 with IE8. I try an AJAX call with:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/events/do_something',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : params,
        beforeSend : function() {
            setPageStateLoading(true);
        },
        success : function(data){
            doSomethingElse(data, false);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest) {
            openErrorDialog(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        },
        complete : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            setPageStateLoading(false);
        }
    });
```

Although the request is successful the error handler gets called because of a parse error. There's nothing wrong with the returned JSON (it works perfectly on Firefox), the problem is line 6229 in jQuery:

```
var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "",
```

Which fails with "Object doesn't support this property or method" and causes a parse error.

Right now I'm using the complete handler with an if statement as a workaround but this isn't really a very good idea. Any ideas on how to fix this properly?

Comment: Could we see the JSON? My bet is that there is a trailing comma somewhere, which breaks in IE but works in other browsers.

Comment: try to get as well the HTTP response Headers to see if it's about the content-type header. You can grab it from firefox with live http headers or firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried leaving dataType unset and then using jQuery's .parseJSON() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)? This way you'll be able to see if there's an error in the response.